# Why I need to IonicModule.forRoot(MyComponent) in order to use InfiniteScroll in component under tests

Tags: angular, ionic3, jestjs

I'm using a stack with Angular 5, Ionic 3 and Jest to test a component in my App. Right now, the tests looks like this:

```
describe("Feed Page", () => {

  let component: FeedPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FeedPage>;

  beforeEach( async() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FeedPage, VideoFrameComponent ],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(FeedPage),
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: CustomErrorHandler, useClass: CustomErrorHandlerMock },
        { provide: NavController, useClass: NavControllerMock },
        { provide: LoadingController, useClass: LoadingControllerMock },
        { provide: VideosServiceProvider, useClass: VideosServiceMock }
      ]
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach( () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent( FeedPage );
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it("can be instancied", () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

There is a lot of setup and one test to check if everything worked fine. The `FeedPage` component uses `InfiniteScroll` from Ionic 3. If I change `IonicModule.forRoot(FeedPage)` for `IonicModule` when running the tests, I got this error:

```
StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[InfiniteScrollContent -> Config]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InfiniteScrollContent -> Config]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Config!
```

Thanks in advance to anyone thats try to help me.